# Enumeration of modules during resolution

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

In the Java Language Specification, paragraph 7.7, it states:

> A 'dependency' is the observable module enumerated by resolution (as described in the **java.lang.module** package specification) for a given 'requires' directive.

The documentation of java.lang.module states:

> Step 1:
> Recursive enumeration takes a set of module names, looks up each of their module declarations, and for each module declaration, recursively enumerates:
>
> - the module names given by the 'requires' directives with the 'transitive' modifier, and
> - at the discretion of the host system, the module names given by the 'requires' directives without the 'transitive' modifier.

I don't understand the purpose of distinguishing between 'requires' and 'requires transitive' when it comes to resolution. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46502453/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: @Sweeper I know the difference between requires and requires transitive but I don't understand why it makes a difference during module resolution

Comment: How would you have written the spec for module resolution otherwise? What do you think the spec should say?

Comment: @Sweeper I think it should simply say: "Step 1: Recursive enumeration takes a set of module names, looks up each of their module declarations, and for each module declaration, recursively enumerates the module names given by the 'requires' directives"

Comment: Is this perhaps awkwardly trying to state that transitive requires get priority over non-transitive ones for resolution, though, 'the host system' is free to ignore that suggestion?

Comment: @rzwitserloot I tried to apply these rules, but I ended up with many unresolved modules...Can you provide an example that illustrates what you have understood?

Comment: Seems to be the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68927394/2711488) but has no answer yet. I’ll will (re)read into the topic tomorrow.